# Как мне получить полный путь к файлу на диске в TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular

Я только изучаю frontend
В Angular приложении мне нужно выбирать файл и передать ссылку на него в backend.
Пробовал это сделать с помощью компонента FileInput @angular/material
Но оказалось, что мне доступно только имя файла, которое, без полного пути к файлу совершенно бесполезно. Оказалось, что в JS нет доступа к файловой системе.
Но как-то же делают это в других приложения. Т.е. получается, что можно обойти это ограничение?
Подскажите как это сделать и какие компоненты в Angular лучше для этого использовать, я имею ввиду для выбора файла.

Comment: Покажи как ты проверял, что есть только имя?

Comment: Назовите хоть одно "другое приложение", которое, работая в браузере, получает полный путь к выбранному пользователем файлу?

Comment: @Yaant, предполагается, что дальше по этому пути нужно получить сам файл. Очевидно, что для этого путь не нужен, а содержимое файла уже есть в компоненте.

Comment: @Grundy очевидно, не всем  это очевидно. :)

Comment: @Grundy, как проверял, если в поле name ни чего не содержится кроме имени файла. Содержимое файла уже есть в компоненте, т.е. вместо ссылки на файл, на backend надо передавать сам файл?

Comment: @alexSerg, а зачем на backend нужен путь на локальной машине, к которой у него нет доступа? Если ты хочешь загрузить файл на сервер, очевидно ты будешь загружать его содержимое сразу.

Comment: согласен, но файл же может быть и на самом сервере. Или, как в моем случае, когда клиент и сервер располагаются на одной машине. Т.е. в любом случае только передавать файл на сервер? Я просто frontend только начал изучать, многое не знаю

Comment: _в любом случае только передавать файл на сервер_